# Set duration for animate camera

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

How can I set the duration of an `animateCamera` in google maps?

```
final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
      controller.animateCamera(...);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know it is not yet implemented.

Source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39810